# Android: random exception

Tags: android, exception, random, stack

after changing activites on my application sometimes i get an exception and i don't know what can be the problem.
This exception occour not in the same activities (but random) and in different function called.

This is the stack:

```
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.TabPayments}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at com.apia.utils.LibLayout.setDisplayMenuContent(LibLayout.java:557)
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at com.apia.selfnettest.TabPayments.onCreate(TabPayments.java:167)
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-11 10:48:34.677: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  ... 11 more
```

It seems that sometimes, the activities cannot draw some resources or open raw files...
thank you...

here the code of "setDisplayMenuContent":

```
public static void setDisplayMenuContent(ArrayList<?> localTabMenu_records, Display display, 
        Activity myactivity, int myId, int BtnResId ) {

    int width = display.getWidth(); 
    int height = display.getHeight(); 
    int N_Tab=3;
    Button btnSelButton = null;
    Button btnUnSelButton = null;

    int Ntab= Math.min(N_Tab, 4);

    if (Ntab>0)
    {


        Button btn1 = null;
        Button btn12= null;
        Button btn2= null;
        Button btn22= null;
        Button btn3= null;  
        Button btn32 = null;
        Button btn0off= null;
        Button btn00off= null;
        Button btn1off= null;
        Button btn11off= null;
        Button btn2off= null;
        Button btn22off= null;


        if (LibController.appLogged) {
            /*ONLINE*/
            btn1 = (Button) myactivity.findViewById(R.id.menu1);
            btn12 = (Button) myactivity.findViewById(R.id.menu12);
            btn2 = (Button) myactivity.findViewById(R.id.menu2);
            btn22 = (Button) myactivity.findViewById(R.id.menu22);
            btn3 = (Button) myactivity.findViewById(R.id.menu3);    
            btn32 = (Button) myactivity.findViewById(R.id.menu32); 
        }else{
            /*OFFLINE*/
            btn0off = (Button) myactivity.findViewById(R.id.menu0off);
            btn00off = (Button) myactivity.findViewById(R.id.menu00off);
            btn1off = (Button) myactivity.findViewById(R.id.menu1off);
            btn11off = (Button) myactivity.findViewById(R.id.menu11off);
            btn2off = (Button) myactivity.findViewById(R.id.menu2off);
            btn22off = (Button) myactivity.findViewById(R.id.menu22off);

        }

        if(localTabMenu_records != null && localTabMenu_records.size() > 0){
            for(int i=0; i<localTabMenu_records.size();i++){    
                RecordTabMenu myRec = (RecordTabMenu) localTabMenu_records.get(i);

                if (LibController.appLogged) {
                    // *********** ONLINE ************  
                    if (myRec.getIdTab().equals("TabWelcome")) 
                    {
                        if (BtnResId == R.id.menu1) {
                            btnSelButton=btn1;
                            btnUnSelButton=btn12;
                        }
                        else {
                            btnSelButton=btn12;
                            btnUnSelButton=btn1;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (myRec.getIdTab().equals("TabAccount"))
                    {
                        if (BtnResId == R.id.menu2) {
                            btnSelButton=btn2;
                            btnUnSelButton=btn22;
                        }
                        else {
                            btnSelButton=btn22;
                            btnUnSelButton=btn2;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (myRec.getIdTab().equals("TabPayments"))
                    {
                        if (BtnResId == R.id.menu3) {
                            btnSelButton=btn3;
                            btnUnSelButton=btn32;
                        }
                        else {
                            btnSelButton=btn32;
                            btnUnSelButton=btn3;
                        }       
                    }    

                }else {

                    // *********** OFFLINE ************
                    if(myRec.getIdTab().equals("TabMainClass"))
                    {
                        if (BtnResId == R.id.menu0off) {
                            btnSelButton=btn0off;
                            btnUnSelButton=btn00off;
                        }
                        else {
                            btnSelButton=btn00off;
                            btnUnSelButton=btn0off;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (myRec.getIdTab().equals("TabContact")) 
                    {
                        if (BtnResId == R.id.menu1off) {
                            btnSelButton=btn1off;
                            btnUnSelButton=btn11off;
                        }
                        else {
                            btnSelButton=btn11off;
                            btnUnSelButton=btn1off;
                        }
                    }else if (myRec.getIdTab().equals("TabInfo"))   
                    {
                        if (BtnResId == R.id.menu2off) {
                            btnSelButton=btn2off;
                            btnUnSelButton=btn22off;
                        }
                        else {
                            btnSelButton=btn22off;
                            btnUnSelButton=btn2off;
                        }
                    }
                }

                String myCaptio = myRec.getTitleTab();
                setButtonPropertiesForLayout(myactivity, i, btnSelButton, height, width, Ntab , myCaptio);

                if (btnUnSelButton != null) {
                    btnUnSelButton.getLayoutParams().width = 0;  // INVISIBLE
                }

            };
        }       

    }


    Button myBtn = (Button) myactivity.findViewById(BtnResId);
    myBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menusel);
}
```

Comment: please post the code around setDisplayMenuContent(LibLayout.java:557)

Comment: The stack trace tells you that something is null on line 557 in your class LibLayout.java. Either post the code like Andy suggests, check whatever objects you are using on that line and make sure that they never are null, or add some error handling.

Comment: Can you post your Manifest.xml code snippet. Also inspect at com.apia.selfnettest.TabPayments.onCreate(TabPayments.java:167) line 167 of TabPayments for nullpointer exception

Comment: the problem is that for 20/30 times opening the "TabPayments" activity (this activity will call setDisplayMenuContent) work perfectly and random i get this error... it seems really that sometimes the myBtn is null (last line of code)

Comment: is:myBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menusel);

Comment: what is at line `(LibLayout.java:557)`

Comment: Not all activities from where u calling this method contains the resource you pass BtnResId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity `Activity myactivit` does not contains resource with id `BtnResId`.

Comment: there is an xml (containing all the buttons) used as menu (bottom scrolling menu) included in each activity. So, in each activity i create, i will pass as "BtnResId" the correct id of the menu button where i am... in this way i think the "BtnResId" is always not null. I get the exception sometimes also in others function... using a global variable that for some reasons become null... note that this variable is set one time when the app is open and never set to null from my activities (maybe android do something...)

Comment: One of the activity is missing this... Please Log the activity name... then you will know which one is missing the resource name BtnResId

Comment: please note that i've post only a piece of "setDisplayMenuContent" otherwise it was to long...

Comment: OK... try this  try {
   Button myBtn = (Button) myactivity.findViewById(BtnResId);
   myBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menusel);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
Log.e("The activity", myactivity.getClass().getName());
Log.e("resource id", "res = " +BtnResId );
  }
 }   and look for the LogCat.... Things will be cleared :)

Comment: ok, now i'll try and i let you know... for the moment, thank you

Comment: i've found the problem... this activity choose the different menu to inflate (because there are two different menu... one for offline and one for online) based on a variable (set to true when i goes online (and never set to false)... for some reason (i dont'know if this is a conseguency of exception or is the real problem), this variable become "false" and the wrong menu is loaded...

Comment: yes, helped me but not sure if it is the real problem... the problem with variable seems to appear after the application crash... and i get also this on stack: 12-11 14:47:00.154: I/Process(583): Sending signal. PID: 583 SIG: 9